# How do I simplify the code in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Here is a code I want to simplify:

```
       public void Method1(Context context, EventLog log = null)
        {
            Class myClass = ConvertToMyClass();
            ApiCall1 apiCall = new ApiCall1(context);
            if (log != null)
            {
                eventLog.WriteEntry("Starting");
            }

            try
            {
                apiCall.Call1(myClass, null, false);
                IsCallSuccess = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (log != null)
                {
                    eventLog.WriteEntry("error");
                }

                IsCallSuccess= false;
                CallErrorMessage = e.Message;
            }
        }

        public void Method2(Context context, EventLog log = null)
        {
            Class myClass = ConvertToMyClass();
            ApiCall2 apiCall = new ApiCall2(context);
            if (log != null)
            {
                eventLog.WriteEntry("Starting");
            }

            try
            {
                apiCall.Call1(myClass);
                NewItemID = myClass.ItemID;
                IsCallSuccess = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (log != null)
                {
                    eventLog.WriteEntry("error");
                }

                IsCallSuccess= false;
                CallErrorMessage = e.Message;
            }
        }

        public void Method3Context context, EventLog log = null)
        {
            Class myClass = ConvertToMyClass();
            ApiCall3 apiCall = new ApiCall3(context);
            if (log != null)
            {
                eventLog.WriteEntry("Starting");
            }

            try
            {
                apiCall.Call3(myClass, "param1");
                UpdatedItemID = myClass.UpdatedItemID;
                IsCallSuccess = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (log != null)
                {
                    eventLog.WriteEntry("error");
                }

                IsCallSuccess= false;
                CallErrorMessage = e.Message;
            }
        }
```

There are 3 methods. I've been thinking about how I could simplify them using delegates or lambdas and didn't find anything.

Your thoughts?

Comment: This might be better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Two ways...

1) Make the method generic, since all three are only different by which class they affect. Which could look something like this:

```
public void Method<T>(Context context, EventLog log = null) where T : BaseAPICall
{
    Class myClass = ConvertToMyClass();
    T apiCall = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), new object[] { context });
    if (log != null)
    {
        eventLog.WriteEntry("Starting");
    }

    try
    {
        apiCall.Call(myClass, null, false);
        IsCallSuccess = true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (log != null)
        {
            eventLog.WriteEntry("error");
        }

        IsCallSuccess= false;
        CallErrorMessage = e.Message;
    }
}
```

or

2) Put those method in the parent class of an appropiate class, in this case, that would be the parent class of ApiCall1/2/3. Which would be:

```
public class BaseAPICall
{
    public abstract Call(Class c, object o, bool b);

    public virtual Method(Context context, EventLog log = null)
    {
        Class myClass = ConvertToMyClass();
        if (log != null)
        {
            eventLog.WriteEntry("Starting");
        }

        try
        {
            this.Call(myClass, null, false);
            IsCallSuccess = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (log != null)
            {
                eventLog.WriteEntry("error");
            }

            IsCallSuccess = false;
            CallErrorMessage = e.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `apiCall.Call` is different for each method, it has different parameters.

Comment: Unify the params or create a overloads of the Call methods. In this case, unifying them would make calling it easier too. Each of them start by a Class, then null or string, so an object? And the last param is a bool, right? BaseAPICall.Call(Class, object, bool)

Comment: I don't have the source of APICall, it's located in a library.

Comment: Not making it easy, are you? This lib expose multiple different type that all take a Call method, but they don't derive from a commom class? From the generic method, create a simple wrapper method around the Call with a switch case, this.Call(typeof(T)). I don't know.